# Gradle project doesn't import classes out of other projects or javax.persistence

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I have several java based projects in **eclipse** and build them via **gradle**. I want to import classes from project B and C into classes of project A. But I always get the error *"The import bc.project.xyz cannot be resolved"*
That happens also when I import the javax.entity.EntityManager.

I imported all dependencies as written in other blogs like:

- [Import other project classes in Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30472067/import-other-project-classes-in-gradle)
- [add glassfish javax.persistence to gradle project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271849/add-glassfish-javax-persistence-to-gradle-project)

But all these suggestions dont work.

Some further details about the system environment:

- java version 1.8.0_72 SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0.72-b15)
- gradle version 5.1.1
- Eclipse IDE 4.12
- Windows 10

The projects are all in the same folder

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile project(":project b")
    testCompile project(path: ':project b', configuration: 'tests')

    compile project(":project c")
    testCompile project(path: ':project c', configuration: 'tests')

    compile group: 'javax.persistence', name: 'persistence-api', version: '1.0'
    compile "javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0"
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Considering the quote *'The definition of insanity is doing the same thing over and over again and expecting a different result'*, I might be insane.

I cloned the project repositories for about 8-10 times and for some reason it works now. I did nothing different, I changed no line of code and still I got a different result. And by different result I mean the right result.

This blog is closed.